# Drupal 7 alter node display

Tags: drupal-7, field, alter, unset

I have a content type with two image fields, banner and logo.

I am trying to implement logic which will allow one of the two to display depending on whether an editor elected to display just the banner or just the logo from radio button options.

I setup a small custom module implementing **hook_node_view** and tried to unset the image field from the node object but no joy. Code fragment below:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
    unset($node->field_main_picture[$node->language][0]);
    unset($node->field_main_picture);
    $node->field_main_picture = null;
}
```

None of those attempts worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

The node object contains an array called **content** which is the renderable data Drupal will print to screen.
It's in that array that my unsets need to take place. I.E:

```
        unset($node->content['field_main_picture']);
```

And the main picture image disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly suggest you to work with [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module when you are programming like that. It allows you to display variables in your page and visualize the tree. For example, you can call `dpm($node)` function in your `hook_node_view()` to see what's in `$node` and how to access it.